# Log kubernetes commands/requests that helm makes

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to debug all kuberenetes commands or api requests to kubernetes which helm makes while executing `helm upgrade` or `helm install`?
For example, I've defined some templates which contain definitions of resource `A` and `B`. I run `helm upgrade --atomic`, then helm creates a release which then creates actual kubernetes resources. In the next version I decided to create a definition of resource `C`(instead of `B`, basically removed definition of resource `B` and added definition of resource `C`). So, on the next run of `helm upgrade` I expect that a new version of the release will remove resource `B`, change resource `A`(if I made changes to it) and then creates resource `C`. So I'd like to be assured that described steps happened. `--debug` option unfortunately doesn't give such information

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is the [helm-diff](https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff) Plugin. It let's you preview the changes an upgrade will do prior to applying, including modified, removed and created resources.
Install using:

```
$> helm plugin install https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff
```

and use by adding `diff` to your helm command:

```
$> helm diff upgrade RELEASE_NAME
```